# Trying to get an ajax call to a php file to work with response in a table

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am trying to query a database via jquery Ajax. I want to select an option and load a table to return a result.

my page make the call is as follows:

```
    <!doctype html>
    <head>


       <script src="jquery/jquery-ui-1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery/jquery-ui-1.11.2/jquery-ui.css">
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="jqueryform/dist/jquery.validate.js"></script>
         <script src="jqueryform/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

  <script>


    $(document).ready(function() {
$('.btnSearch').click(function(){



 });

    $('form').submit(function(e){

});

function makeAjaxRequest() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'addithandle1.php',
        type: 'get',
        data: {name: $('input#batchtype').val()},
        success: function(response) {


     $('table#resultTable tbody').html(response);
        }
    });
}

</script>


</head>

<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="">IgG Dashboard</a>

        </div>

        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li><a href="Login_success.php">New Handover</a></li>
            <li><a href="oldfiles.php">Old Handovers</a></li>
            <li><a href="dgam.php">Formulations</a></li>
            <li><a href="current.php">Current Processing</a></li>
            <li><a href="midanamenu.php">Analysis</a></li>
             <li><a href="oldfiles.php">Other</a></li>
             <li id= "dash"><p  >Welcome <?php echo "  " 

    .$_SESSION['myuser']."  ";?><a class="btn bg-info" href="adm.php">Admin Panel</a></p></li>
                  </ul>
                </div><!-- /.nav-collapse -->
              </div><!-- /.container -->
            </div><!-- /.navbar -->
            <br><br><br><br><br>
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row-fluid">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
            <?php
        include "config.php";

     // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
    {

    }
    else
    {
      $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM script ");

      echo " <Form  method='get'> <label>Script :</label> <select  name='batchtype' >";

    }

   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {   

        echo "<option value = '".$row['scriptname']."'>".$row['scriptname']."</option>";

     } 
  echo "</select>";  
           echo "<button  class='btn-search'>Load Script </button></form>";


?>
<table id="resultTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>scriptname</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
            </div>
            </div>
```

So when this page loads it make a PHP call to genertate the form  AND  PARTS. It has to be this way as the the options are input in the back end of the site and echoed to the front end.

I am then trying to select an option click submit and pull a row from my database and return to my #resultstable. My PHP file is as follows.

```
     <?php
include 'config.php';

$batchtype2 = ($_GET['batchtype']);
 $batchtype2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$batchtype2);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM script WHERE scriptname  = '".$batchtype2."' ";       
  $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

$count=mysqli_num_rows($result);

if($count==0 ){
    echo "</br></br></br></br></br></br></br><p> No Matching results found</p>";
}

else{
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

        echo '<td>'.$row['scriptname'].'</td>';


 }
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

The function is changing the url and make some kindof request but I am not getting the desired result in the table(no data)

I have tried to adapt the code from a tutorial, one of few I can find that output a table back to the page.

Any help will be much appreciated. I can handle all this with just PHP but want to make my page more dynamic so am trying to explore AJAX

Also worth adding that the php script works without the ajax.

Comment: Please go indent your code properly and remove all of the extra spacing.

Answer (score 0):

When replacing the content of a tbody element your response should contain `<tr>`-elements

Comment: does the rest of it look okay to you? still not working on with tr in place

Comment: Your code is a bit hard to read and not well organised. A lot of things can go wrong here so determine what causes the problem:
- is the submit performed?
- does the request return anything?
- are there any errors?

A tool like Firebug can help you with that.